# How to make a path in python and display it on a qml canvas

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml

I'm trying to create a path in python and display it inside a qml canvas but I can't manage to make it work.

I have tried to make a @QtCore.pyqtSlot but the type don't seems to be supported.

Here is my minimal model :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

class PathModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        self.path.addRect(50,50,100,100)
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(result = QtCore.QVariant)
    def returnPath(self):
        return self.path
```

and the qml file :

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.11


Window {
    id: root
     Rectangle {
        id: conteneurCanvas
        Canvas {
            id: mycanvas
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            contextType: "2d"
            onPaint: {
                context.path = path_model.returnPath();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to dynamically create it through some js code but I'm not very familiar with this language so I did something like this witch obviously doesn't work.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.11


Window {
    id: root
     Rectangle {
        id: conteneurCanvas
        Canvas {
            id: mycanvas
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            contextType: "2d"

            Path {
                id: myPath
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                // All the elements will be send through slot but for the exemple ...
                myPath.PathLine { x: i*100 ; y: 100 }
            } 

            onPaint: {
                context.path = myPath;
                context.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the correct syntax in this tuto :

https://master.qt.io/learning/developerguides/canvastutorial/QtQuickCanvasTutorial.pdf

In the end we got this kind of syntax :

```
Window {
    id: root
     Rectangle {
        id: conteneurCanvas
        Canvas {
            id: mycanvas
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            contextType: "2d"

            onPaint: {
                context.beginPath()
                context.moveTo(0,0)
                for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    // Do what you want
                    context.lineTo(i*20,10*i*i)
                } 
                context.lineWidth = 1;
                context.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
}
```